# Magento Category ReDirect

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, categories

I have a small issue but I have been battling for two days now to resolve it.

I have recently recreated a new category (www.site.co.za/mens-clothing-3) which is populated and working. I want to redirect (www.site.co.za/mens-clothing) to the new category (www.site.co.za/mens-clothing-3).

I have tried implementing the following in the htacess file, but nothing happens. The old category links (mens-clothing) goes obviosuly now to a 404 and it is still being picked up by Google (main concern). My htaccess rule looks like this:

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} bigblue.co.za$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mens-clothing-3
RewriteRule ^mens-clothing/(.*)$ http://www.bigblue.co.za/mens-clothing-3/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use magento url redirect instead

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index

:)

Comment: The link worked but it kept on regenerating new links i.e. www.google.co.za/product-4 (the digit kept increasing). I am not currently standing on product-8 which is in no way suitable for my Google ranking/s.

Please assist where possible. I have also tried unticking the "Create Permanent Redirect for old URL" in the Category url re-write. 

What could I possible be doing wrong?